# Keep selected value in Dropdown SQL PHP

Tags: php, sql, select, dropdown

Since i couldn't find anything that solved my problem, i thought i should ask it here.

I have 2 dropdowns with a submit button, the values save in my database.

The problem is that when i refresh my page, the dropdown value goes back to the first value, so the dropdown values doesn't change to the database value.

**Example:**

PHP Table: https://i.gyazo.com/b5eb036d8cb9407132ff39b67434ed65.png

Database: https://i.gyazo.com/fab5eca498dc566383de092c687f7f01.png

**PHP Code:**

```
<form action="submit_stdntdetails.php" method="post">
                      <select name="potentieel" id="potentieel">
                             <option value="volvo">Volvo XC90</option>
                             <option value="saab">Saab 95</option>
                             <option value="mercedes">Mercedes SLK</option>
                             <option<?php if ($potentieel == "Loaned"): ?> 
                             selected="selected"<?php endif; ? 
                             >>Loaned</option>
                      </select>       

                 <?"</td>";
                 echo "<td>"?>

                     <select name="prestatie">
                            <option value="volvo">Volvo XC90</option>
                            <option value="saab">Saab 95</option>
                            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes SLK</option>
                            <option value="audi">Audi TT</option>
                     </select>

                  <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="
                             border-top-width: 1px;
                             border-bottom-width: 1px;">

 </form>


                  <?"</td>";
```

**submit_stdntdetails.php:**

```
if(isset($_POST['potentieel'])){
   $potentieel=$_POST['potentieel'];
}

if(isset($_POST['prestatie'])){
   $prestatie=$_POST['prestatie'];
}



$sql = "UPDATE employees
   SET potentieel = '$potentieel', prestatie = '$prestatie'
   WHERE ID = 1";
```

As you can see i changed the last option to try if that worked, but it doesn't
Hope someone could help me, thanks

Comment: $potentieel contain database value right?

Comment: No, i did not put anything in $potentieel. It was just an experiment

Comment: So how we decide which value is selected?

Answer (score 1):

Use $_SESSION variables to set the select default. When the form is submitted, set your $_SESSION['yourVarName'] equal to the $_GET or $_POST data.  This is how I have done this in the past.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php